# How to reduce cognitive complex in javascript event handler?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, sonarqube, nested-statement, cognitive-complexity

I have some element event handler uses if statement inside, why sonar complains this if statement causes cognitive complexity? Is there a way I can avoid this or improve this?

```
const handleOnBlur = () => {
    if (isEditMode) {
        setMyStuff(false);
    }
};
```

This is counted as code smell +2, including 1 for nesting. Why if statement causes code smell especially I don't have very complex if, else or nested if statements.

Thank you!

Comment: Such complexity is a necessary result of (any useful) logic an app implements. You can't eliminate it, but in some cases, reducing it when possible helps. You can think of it a bit like LoC. Aim isn't to reduce it to 0, but to make an attempt to keep things DRY so it isn't a lot larger than it needs to be.

Comment: Can you post the entire sonarcube message, please?

Comment: In sonarcube it just says brain-overload, and for the if above it increase the complexity by +2 and says "include 1 for nesting"

Comment: I am in react, and even for component conditional generation, I get +1 complexity.   My code is like this: {showMyInputInViewMode && (
                <MyInputText readOnly="true" />
            )}
{!showMyInputTextInViewMode && (
               <div  onBlur={handleOnBlur}>
      ...
      </div>
            )}

Comment: for each && above the code complexity +1